# htmlfontify-buffer will underline spelling errors, even when LocalWords: are present

Tags: emacs, flyspell

I use htmlfontify-buffer to render source code with syntax highlighting to my work colleagues in HTML (they do not all use EMACS). I use flyspell to correct my horrible spelling :) in comments. When flyspell mistakenly thinks a word is misspelled I add that word to the LocalWords: . This works while editing - no more false spelling errors in my comments.

However, when htmlfontify-buffer runs it appears to not respect the LocalWords: and marks the words as misspelled in the HTML.

How might I fix this small problem? Any help appreciated. Martin M